# Where in the android SDK source code are protobuf encoded AndroidManifest.xml files created?

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers

I am trying to take an AAB produced during an automated build process and then change various values (package name, app version, facebook API key, etc) in the base/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml file contained within the AAB archive prior to submission to the Google Play Store.

AAB's contain a 'protobuf encoded' AndroidManifest.xml such that it can not be modified using XML utilities as I have previously done. I have extensively searched the Android source tree trying to find the code responsible for taking an XML document version of the AndroidManifest.xml and producing a protobuf encoded version and have come up mostly empty.

I want to use this code to do one of two things:

1) Convert the protobuf encoded XML document back to XML, modify, and then reencode

2) Directly modify the protobuf encoded XML document without conversion

Can anyone point me to source/classes in the Android SDK source tree (https://android.googlesource.com) that may help?

Comment: I am trying to do exactly the same. Well, in my case it is just to read it. I am checking out this node package called proto-parse but I am still unsure if it will help me.